# How to decrypt RSA file with openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl

I have 3 files `publickey.pem`, `aeskey.rsa.enc` and `img.png.aes.enc`. I know that I could use `openssl` to decrypt the png file, but I simply don't know how to do it.

Comment: `man pkeyutl || man rsautl`

Comment: hope this will help: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Encrypt_and_decrypt_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html

Comment: If you don't have the private key, you're not going to succeed.